# how to calculate a $95\%$ confidence interval for the true concentration?

Tags: confidence-interval

The following are the results of $10$ attempts to measure the concentration of nitrate ions in $\mu$g/mL in a specimen of water:

$\{0.513, 0.524, 0.529, 0.481, 0.492, 0.499, 0.518, 0.49, 0.494, 0.501\}$

Could anyone tell me how to calculate a $95\%$ confidence interval for the true concentration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote your data as $x_i$, $i = 1, 2, ... 10$. First, compute the sample mean as

$\bar x=\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$

and sample variance

$s^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)^2$,

where $n = 10$. The confidence interval is $[c_1, c_2]$ where

$c_1=\bar x - \frac{s}{\sqrt n}\times t_{\alpha/2}(n-1)$ and $c_2=\bar x + \frac{s}{\sqrt n}\times t_{\alpha/2}(n-1)$,

where $t_{\alpha/2}(n-1)=2.2622$ for $n=10$ and confidence level of 95%.

Comment: One note to user295357's answer above (because I can't comment): they assume that the data is relatively Normally distributed; you may want to consider if that is true given your prior knowledge of what is supposed to be the distribution of the observed measurement of nitrate ions in a specimen of water.

Comment: Thankssssssssssssssssssssssssss

Comment: Could you tell me what are the assumption you have made for the confidence interval to be valid?

Comment: Could you justify the statement: 'Quadrupling the sample size halves the width of the confidence interval' ..Thanks

Comment: NO,  a confidence interval analysis here, potentially addressing toxicity thresholds, is likely inappropriate. See my edited answer.

Comment: @AJKOER: You are asserting facts not included in the Question. There is no way to tell--just from the Question--whether this is a routine textbook problem or a life-and-death actual medical situation with an unstated 'danger' level. You may be right, and you are of course entitled to your opinion, but if you are going to dismiss other answers as irresponsible, you might do everyone the courtesy of providing references about what you fear may be true. // BTW, just upvoted your Answer anyhow to cancel mystery downvote. (It takes a lot to get a downvote from me.)

Comment: @BruceET Thanks for the honest feedback. I have added source links as requested. My suggestion, however, but briefly browse the likely more accurate second one.

Answer (score 3):

By the 'true concentration' I assume you refer to the mean $\mu$ of the
population from which your $n = 10$ measurements are essentially a random sample.

**For normal data, a t confidence interval.** Just based on a sample of ten, it is difficult to know whether the
population is normal, but the observations do not seem to be markedly skewed and there are no outliers. [All of your observations lie within a relatively narrow interval between 0.48 and 0.53, so it is reasonable to conclude that the 'true concentration', whatever you may mean by that,
is likely not far from these two values.]

```
x = c(0.513, 0.524, 0.529, 0.481, 0.492, 
      0.499, 0.518, 0.49, 0.494, 0.501)
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.4810  0.4925  0.5000  0.5041  0.5168  0.5290 

boxplot(x, horizontal=T)
```

[image]

Also, a Shapiro-Wilk test in R does not reject the null hypothesis that the data are sampled from a normal distribution.

```
shapiro.test(x)

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  x
 W = 0.94658, p-value = 0.6283
```

Thus it seems reasonable to assume that the data are normal and to
make a 95% t confidence interval (CI) for $\mu.$ In R, this is part of
the procedure `t.test`; the CI is $(0.493, 0.516).$ [This type of interval is discussed by @user295357 (+1).]

```
t.test(x)$conf.int
[1] 0.4926521 0.5155479
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
```

---

**Nonparametric bootstrap CI.** If you have previous experience with this kind of measurement and
doubt that the data are normal, then you might want to make a 95%
nonparametric bootstrap confidence interval. Such a CI does not
depend on the assumption that data are normal (However, ten observations
may not be enough for reliable bootstrapping.)

Bootstrapping takes repeated samples. with replacement, of size $n = 10$
from you observed data `x` in order to approximate the variability of
$\bar X =  0.5041$ as an estimate of $\mu.$ One simple style of nonparametric bootstrap CI is found below: $(0.495, 0.514),$ which is
not much different from the 95% t confidence interval found above.

```
x = c(0.513, 0.524, 0.529, 0.481, 0.492, 
      0.499, 0.518, 0.49, 0.494, 0.501)
a.obs = mean(x);  a.obs
[1] 0.5041
set.seed(1208)
d.re = replicate(3000, mean(sample(x,10,rep=T)) - a.obs)
UL = quantile(d.re, c(.975, .025))
a.obs - UL
    97.5%      2.5% 
0.4945975 0.5136000
```

(If you are not familiar with bootstrap CIs, and want a little more explanation as to what the R code does, then feel free to ask.)

---

**Wilcoxon nonparametric CI.** Another kind of nonparametric CI is for the population *median* $\eta.$
[If the population is symmetrical, the mean (if it exists) and median will be the same.] It uses the same methods as a one-sample Wilcoxon signed-rank test.
In R, it can be found as below:  $(0.492, 0.516),$ again not much different from the CIs above.

```
wilcox.test(x, conf.int=T)$conf.int
[1] 0.4920 0.5155
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
```

---

Unless you have reason to believe the measurements are not normal, you should use the t confidence interval shown first above. If you do suspect non-normal data, you could choose between the bootstrap and Wilcoxon
nonparametric intervals.

Comment: Thankssssssssssssssssssssssssss but I do not understand anything of your answer

Comment: Could you tell me what are the assumption you have made for the confidence interval to be valid?

Comment: Could you justify the statement: 'Quadrupling the sample size halves the width of the confidence interval'

Comment: _Understand nothing:_ Sorry about that. Not really surprised, often happens when Q shows no specific effort toward solution. Recommend you skip bootstrap. Look at your text and class notes for t and Wilcoxon. _Assumptions:_ There are 3 types of CIs. For t: Random sample from normal population. For Bootstrap: Random sample from population for which mean and variance exist. For W: Same, best if pop. dist'n is symmetrical, continuous.// _Quadruple/half_ (on avg). Approx.  t CIs, $\bar X \pm 2S/\sqrt{25}$ has width $(4/5)S=0.8S.$ Compare: $\bar X \pm 2S/\sqrt{100}$ has width $(4/10)S = 0.4S.$

Comment: NO, I do not recommend a tighter confidence interval analysis here, as there may be potentially an issue with toxicity thresholds. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you explore the concept of a prediction interval. To quote [a source](https://www.statisticshowto.com/prediction-interval/#:%7E:text=A%20prediction%20interval%20is%20a,often%20confused%20with%20each%20other):

> A prediction interval is a type of confidence interval (CI) used with predictions in regression analysis; it is a range of values that predicts the value of a new observation, based on your existing model. Prediction and confidence intervals are often confused with each other.

My rationalization is your reference to 'the true concentration' for your current experiment, a one-time event.

[EDIT] An important point, as prediction intervals add a measure of volatility, the interval is wider. Now, in the particular context of nitrate concentration, not likely considered by my colleagues, are the implications of an improper prediction that crosses over the toxicity threshold for nitrate poisoning. In that event, livestock perishes and, with respect to people, the young (especially babies) face a significant fatality risk.

Also, nitrate concentration is generated from ammonia in the presence of select bacteria.  As such, its concentration should not be viewed as a stable fixed unknown amount, but possibly variable in nature (subject to favorable conditions promoting its formation).

Does anyone still wish to make recommendations based on a confidence interval analysis here? Even a prediction interval, in my opinion, may actually prove to be too conservative. Knowledge of the generating model is likely required to render a responsible short term opinion.

[EDIT][EDIT] Per request, added sources starting with the somewhat milder comments on nitrate sources and poisoning courtesy of the CDC [available here](https://www.cdc.gov/healthywater/drinking/private/wells/disease/nitrate.html). More disturbing are statements that can be [found here](https://www.poison.org/articles/causes-and-symptoms-of-nitrate-nitrite-poisoning-174#:%7E:text=Poisoning%20can%20result%20from%20swallowing,are%20shallow%20or%20poorly%20constructed).

Comment: Thankssssssssssssssssssssssssss

Answer (score 1):

Maybe also the derivation is interesting for you. Assume that your data follows a normal distribution i.e. $X_i\overset{iid}{\sim}N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Then the mean $\overline{X}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ follows a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$. Now look at the standardized random variable $Z=\frac{\overline{X}-E(\overline{X})}{\sqrt{Var(\overline{X}})}=\frac{\overline{X}-\mu}{\sqrt{\sigma^2/n}}=\frac{\overline{X}-\mu}{\sigma}\sqrt{n}$ (this expression should look familiar to you). The standardized random variable $Z$ follows a standard normal distribution, i.e. $Z\sim N(0,1)$. Let $c$ denote the $1-\frac{\alpha}{2}$ quantile of $N(0,1)$. The following holds:
\begin{align}
&Pr(-c\leq \frac{\overline{X}-\mu}{\sigma}\sqrt{n}\leq c)=1-\alpha \\
\leftrightarrow & Pr\left(-c\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\leq\overline{X}-\mu\leq c\frac{\sigma} {\sqrt{n}}\right)=1-\alpha \\
\leftrightarrow & Pr\left(-\overline{X}-c\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\leq-\mu\leq -\overline{X}+c\frac{\sigma} {\sqrt{n}}\right)=1-\alpha \\
\leftrightarrow & Pr\left(\overline{X}+c\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\geq\mu\geq \overline{X}--c\frac{\sigma} {\sqrt{n}}\right)=1-\alpha \\
\leftrightarrow & Pr\left(\overline{X}-c\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\leq\mu\leq \overline{X}+c\frac{\sigma} {\sqrt{n}}\right)=1-\alpha
\end{align}
Now choose $\alpha=5\%$ and calculate the 97.5% quantile $c_{0.975}=1.96$ and you can calculate the confidence interval for $\mu$ $\textbf{if}$ the variance is known. But the variance is unknown and must be estimated. An unbiased estimator for the variance $\sigma^2$ is
\begin{equation}
S^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\overline{X})^2
\end{equation}
,i. e. $E(S^2)=\sigma^2$. Now replace $\sigma$ in the expression $Z$ by $S$ and call this expression $t$:
\begin{equation}
t=\frac{\overline{X}-\mu}{\sqrt{S}}\sqrt{n}
\end{equation}
It can be shown that this expression follows a t distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom. So you have to replace $c$ with the $1-\frac{\alpha}{2}%$ quantile of the $ t(n-1)$ distribution.

To cut a long story short:

1. Calculate the sample mean $\overline{X}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$
2. Calculate the sample variance: $S^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\overline{X})^2$
3. Calculate the $1-\frac{\alpha}{2}$ quantile of the $t(n-1)$-distribution (n is your sample size) and call it $c$.
4. Calculate the confidence interval $CI=\left[\overline{X}-c\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}; \overline{X}+c\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}\right]$ $(S=\sqrt{S^2})$

and you are done. But be careful, this only applies if the population is normally distributed. In practice it is therefore usual to first check whether the data is normally distributed. There are many tests for that (notice you can only test if the data is significantly against the assumption of a normal distribution). For example Jarque-Bera-Test, Shapiro-Wilk-Test, Ks-Test (but with estimated parameters for $\mu$ and $\sigma$ you have to use Lillifors-Test) and many more. Even if the data is not normally distributed, the interval for $n\geq 30$ can usually be regarded as an approximate confidence interval due to the central limit theorem.

I hope this answer is helpful.

Comment: thanksssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss